# Introduce a div between a loop to add flex

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is what I currently have which displays fine.

I end up with 4 rows and 4 columns.

```
<div>
{(
    <Table
    data={{
        body: Object.keys(conduitData).map((key) => {
        const conduitArray = conduitData[key];
        return conduitArray.map(category => ({
            content:
            <div>
                <ConduitSelector
                data={{title: category.name}}
                />
            </div>
        }));
        }),
    }}
    />
)}
</div>
```

But the CSS does not wrap and the content keeps squeezing into the same row.

I want it to flex down if there is more than 3 items in a row.

I want to be able to wrap each row into another div so that I could introduce flex css properties as follows:

**conduitData** is a map.

**conduitArray** is an array.

```
<div>
{(
    <Table
    data={{
        body: Object.keys(conduitData).map((key) => {
        const conduitArray = conduitData[key];
        
        // (parent) I want to add this div to introduce css flex 
        return <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            {conduitArray.map(category => ({
            content:
            // adding flex properties here too
            <div style={{flex: '0 0 33.333333%'}}>
                <ConduitSelector
                data={{title: category.name,}}
                />
            </div>,
        }))}
        </div>
        }),
    }}
    />
)}
</div>
```

But when I run this, I end up with the following error.

> Error!row.map is not a function

Is there a way I could overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you cant put the styles in the  surrounding your Table.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <conduit div style="flex-basis: 33.333333%">
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT

maybe wrap around the return function instead?

```
return <div>{ conduitArray.map(category => ({
          content:
          <div>
              <ConduitSelector
              data={{title: category.name}}
              />
          </div>
  })) }</div>;
```

Comment: The table produces a 4 row by 4 column output (assume a 4 square by 4 square).  I want to control each of these rows on its own and flex down if there is more than 3 in a row but in no way affect the next row. So essentially would end up with 8 rows. per row 3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1 if that makes sense. So 3 per row, 1 flexes down. This solution will not achieve that.

Comment: I understand, sorry for my non-helpful advice. could you wrap the div around the return then?

Comment: Np, thanks for trying. That's what I done above. It returns a Error!row.map is not a function error.